# Как подключить библиотеку к Cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

Я всегда писал код в visual studio совершенно не парясь ни о чём, но теперь
я пытаюсь написать небольшую программку, которая будет работать как на windows, так и на linux.

Хорошо, я создал проект Cmake, теперь мне нужно подключить библиотеки (glm, glfw, sockpp)

Glm и glfw я подключил, просто скопировав репозиторий из гитхаба и прописав в cmakelists.txt
`add_subdirecory([путь до папки])
target_link_libraries(myproject [название библиотеки из её cmakelists])`

Но с sockpp возникла проблема, при сборке компилятор пишет
**Ошибка    LNK1104 не удается открыть файл "sockpp.lib"**
При этом проект нормально собирается  утилитой Cmake gui, но он выплевывает проект visual studio, а мне нужна кроссплатформенность.

Правильно ли я подключаю библиотеки к своему проекту? Как их нужно подключать?

Если я хочу подключить библиотеку, которая не содержит cmakelists.txt, а только makefile, (например asio) то как быть?

Есть ли пути написания кроссплатформенных программ без Cmake?

Comment: Тут слишком много вопросов в одном вопросе. Cmake для написания кроссплатформенных программ не нужен вообще. Зато нужен тулсет для кросс компиляции или машина нативным тулсетом для целевой платформы. А подключать разные библиотеки на разных платформах в cmake придется очень по-разному.

Answer (score -1):

можно взять то что есть, что выдал cmake gui и вставлять в CMakeList.txt конструкции вроде

`if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL Windows)`

```
ориентированное на платформу

include_directories ("d:/library/include")
link_directories( "d:/library/lib") 
set( REQUIRED_LIBRARIES asio)
```

`elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL Linux)`

ориентированное на платформу

```
include_directories ("/usr/local/include")
link_directories( "/usr/local/lib") 
set( REQUIRED_LIBRARIES asio)`
```

`endif()`

приблизительно так